# Is it correct to use "huge amount of " with the words "passion and desire"?

Tags: grammar

Can we use "Huge amount of" with the words "passion" and "Desire"? In other words , is it correct to say that , "there is a huge amount of passion and desire inside me to do this task " OR "I feel huge amount of passion and desire for doing the task"

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can say "great passion"

Comment: I feel a great passion to do this , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you *can* refer to *a [huge | large | great] [**amount | quantity | measure**] of [passion | love | hatred]*

But *in practice* we don't usually use those highlighted terms in the context of "quantifying / intensifying" abstract emotional states. The only "amount" construction that comes to mind is the somewhat idiosyncratic *[not without] a **certain amount** of passion* - a "facetiously understated" alternative to the more common form *[with] a **great deal** of passion*.

[Here's a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20huge%20amount%20of%20passion%2Ca%20great%20deal%20of%20passion&year_start=1821&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20huge%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20great%20deal%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0) showing just how much we avoid ***amount*** in favour of ***deal*** in such contexts...

[image]

...where the *lower* blue line wouldn't look much different even if I had the NGram skills to make it combine all instances of ***huge, tremendous, surprising, considerable*** along with ***great***. The other two ["most common"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20%2A%20amount%20of%20passion&year_start=1821&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20%2A%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20certain%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20considerable%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20tremendous%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20fair%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20great%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20huge%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20surprising%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ca%20*%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20certain%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20considerable%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20tremendous%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20fair%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20great%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20huge%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20surprising%20amount%20of%20passion%3B%2Cc0) adjectives for this context *(**certain, fair**)* are both a bit "quirky", as indicated above.

---

TL;DR: Words like ***amount*** and ***quantity*** are a bit too closely associated with *precisely quantifiable measure* to work well with amorphous abstract emotional states. Exceptions to this general principle are mostly relatively formal / literary / facetious "frozen forms" such as *a **certain amount | great deal** of [emotion]*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Although neither are easily quantifiable, there are certainly degrees of both passion and desire.